# In SQL what is the best way to find empty values in two tables, where the value should contain data

Tags: sql

I have two tables, 1 is my list of invited guests with their name, email and total guests invited. My other is my response list, their email, total guest RSVP per email, and their confirmation that they responded. Need to select the records of those that have a confirmation response with no guests RSVP, with total invited to send them a reminder.

Comment: What do your tables look like? What have you tried so far that we can build on or use to guide you? Do you have sample data? Do you know how to join tables using SQL?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Here are some [tips](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/271055/tips-for-asking-a-good-structured-query-language-sql-question/271056#271056) on how to ask question related to sql. From your question what I can gather is you need joins but you need to provide more details.

Comment: Why two different tables?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product. Please add a [tag](https://stackoverflow.com/help/tagging) for the database product you are using `postgresql`, `oracle`, `sql-server`, `db2`, ...

Comment: Please **[edit]** your question and add some [sample data](http://plaintexttools.github.io/plain-text-table/) and the expected output based on that data. [Formatted text](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/251362) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). ([edit] your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments)